# Potential source/sink flow. (Shifted in polar coordinates)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, potential-flow

I was wondering how does the equation of velocity for potential source flow shifted from the origin to (R,Alpha)(this are the center coordinates) look like? Can anyone write a formula for this? I was trying to find out myself, but I don't understand how to adjust flow rate or source intensity to another reference frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift of origin is easy in Cartesian coordinates. Velocity potential for source/sink flow is $$\phi=K\ln r,\quad K\equiv\frac{m}{2\pi}$$ where $m$ is source/sink strength with appropriate sign. Since $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we have $$\phi=\frac{K}{2}\ln (x^2+y^2)$$

If the source/sink is located at $(R,\theta_0)$ then its  location in Cartesian coordinates is $(x_0,y_0)=(R\cos\theta_0,R\sin\theta_0)$. Shifting source/sink away from the origin gives $$\phi=\frac{K}{2}\ln ((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2)$$ Substituting $$(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$$ takes you back to polar coordinates.

Comment: Oh thank you, it is what I need. :)